# Proof of Klingenberg's lemma in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The following is Exercise 10.1 in *Riemannian Geometry* by M. do Carmo.

> **(Klingenberg's Lemma).** Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature $K<K_0$, where $K_0$ is a positive constant. Let $p,q\in M$ and let $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ be two distinct geodesics joining $p$ to $q$ with $\ell(\gamma_0)<\ell(\gamma_1)$. Assume that $\gamma_0$ is homotopic to $\gamma_1$, that is, there exists a continuous family of curves $\alpha_t$, $t\in[0,1]$ such that $\alpha_0=\gamma_0$ and $\alpha_1=\gamma_1$. Prove that there exists $t_0\in(0,1]$ such that $$\ell(\gamma_0)+\ell(\alpha_{t_0})\geq\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{K_0}}.$$

The hint goes:

> *Hint:* Assume $\ell(\gamma_0)<\pi/\sqrt{K_0}$ (otherwise, we have nothing to prove). From Ranch's Theorem, $\exp_p:TpM\to M$ has no critical point in the open ball $B$ of radius $\pi/\sqrt{K_0}$, centered at $p$. For $t$ small, it is possible to lift the curve at to the tangent space $T_pM$, i.e., there exists a curve $\widetilde{\alpha}_t$ in $T_pM$, joining $\exp_p^{-1}(0)=0$ to $\exp_p^{-1}(q)=\widetilde{q}$, such that $\exp_p\circ\widetilde{\alpha}_t=\alpha_t$. It is clear that it is not possible to do the same for every $t\in[0,1]$, since $\gamma_1$ cannot be lifted keeping the endpoints fixed.
>
> We conclude that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $t(\varepsilon)$ such that $\alpha_{t(\varepsilon)}$ can be lifted to $\tilde{\alpha}_{t(\varepsilon)}$ and $\tilde{\alpha}_{t(\varepsilon)}$ contains points with distance
> $<\varepsilon$ from the boundary $\partial B$ of $B$. In the contrary case, for some $\varepsilon>0$, all lifts $\tilde{\alpha}_t$ are at the distance $\geq\varepsilon$ from $\partial B$; the set of $t$'s for which it is possible to lift $\alpha_t$ will then be open and closed and $\alpha_1$ could be lifted, which is a contradiction. Therefore, for all $\varepsilon>0$, we have $$\ell(\gamma_0)+\ell(\alpha_{t(\varepsilon)})\geq\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{K_0}}-\varepsilon.$$ Now choose a sequence $\{\varepsilon_n\}\to0$, and consider a convergent subsequence of $\{t(\varepsilon_n)\}\to t_0$. Then there exists a curve $\alpha_{t_0}$ with $$\ell(\gamma_0)+\ell(\alpha_{t_0})\geq\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{K_0}}.$$

Why do such liftings exist? We only know that $\exp_p$ is nonsingular on $B(0,R):=\{v\in T_pM:|v|<R\}$, *not* that $\exp_p|_{B(0,R)}$ is a covering map or anything. Local diffeomorphisms can behave badly when it comes to lifting curves! So here is my question:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $p\in M$. Suppose $\exp_p$ is nonsingular everywhere on $B(0,R)\subset T_pM$. Does any curve on $M$ starting from $p$ with length $<R$ lift to a curve on $T_pM$ starting at $0$? What about homotopies of such curves? In particular, why does the hint works?

Another question:

> While in do Carmo's book this result is called Klingenberg's lemma, I cannot find it in any other resource. When and in which paper did Klingenberg prove this?

Comment: In which way can $exp_p$ behave badly? It is a diffeomorphism (meaning smooth isomorphism with smooth inverse) between $B(0,R)$ and its image in $M$.

Comment: @quarague Of course it is _not_ a diffeomorphism! Being nonsingular does not mean being injective. Just consider quotients of spheres.

Comment: Nonsingular alone doesn't guarantee injectivity. But it is a general property of the exponential map of a Riemannian manifold that it is a diffeomorphism for a sufficiently small ball around $0$ (smaller than the injectivity radius), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)

Comment: @quarague We are _not_ working inside the injectivity radius. Your argument only gives the lower bound $2\operatorname{inj}(M)$ in place of $2\pi/\sqrt{K_0}$. And one cannot get any estimate of the injectivity radius from curvature alone. All you know is that it behaves well in a very small neighborhood, but you have no control on how small that is.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please point out your reason so that I can edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the question:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $p\in M$. Suppose $\exp_p$ is nonsingular everywhere on $B(0,R)\subset T_pM$. Does any curve on $M$ starting from $p$ with length $<R$ lift to a curve on $T_pM$ starting at $0$?

The answer to this in general is negative: Some curves do lift but some do not.  However, the statement in your question is **not** what do Carmo is claiming. He only claims that if $\gamma: [0,a]\to M$ is a geodesic with $\gamma(0)=p$ then for all sufficiently small $T>0$ the restriction $\gamma|_{[0,T]}$ lifts to $T_pM$ via the exponential map to a radial line segment. This statement is obvious since $\exp_p$ is a local diffeomorphism at $0\in T_pM$.

Edit. I indeed misread the question. Here is the correct answer. One needs to assume that the curve $\alpha_0$ lifts. The map $\exp_p$ is a local diffeomorphism on $B(0, \pi/\sqrt{K_0})$. The same argument as in the proof of the covering homotopy theorem yields:

Lemma. Suppose that $f: X\to Y$ is a local homeomorphism between manifolds, $H:[0,1]^2\to Y$ is a continuous map and the curve $H(s,0), s\in [0,1]$ lifts to a curve $\tilde\alpha_0(s)=\tilde{H}(s,0)$ in $X$ via $f$. Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that the restriction of $H$ to $[0,1]\times [0,\epsilon]$ lifts to a map $\tilde{H}:[0,1]\times [0,\epsilon]\to X$ via $f$, whose restriction to $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ is the curve $\tilde\alpha_0$.

This lemma yields the claim made by do Carmo.

Comment: It is not $\gamma|_{[0,T]}$ but $\alpha_T$ being lifted. The $T$ denotes time in a homotopy. Please read the question more carefully. What do Carmo's claiming is that we can always lift the homotopy $\alpha_t$ for small $t$ such that $\tilde{\alpha}_t$ has a _fixed_ endpoint $\tilde{q}\in\exp_p^{-1}(q)$. Then he argues that his is not possible to do it for all $t$, since if we lift $\gamma_1$ then we clearly get a different endpoint. Besides, you did not give any counterexample when you claimed that the answer is negative.

Comment: The curve $\alpha_0$ automatically lifts since it is a geodesic:  $\alpha(t)=\exp_p(t\alpha_0'(0))$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: This is not apparent from the way the question was written, but, surely, this is what do Carmo had in mind.